# Web Image, Image won't show

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

[Simple Tutorial for WebImage](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/0bbc555a-0a4e-4774-a580-fa804c570458/?WebImage%20Helper%20in%20ASP.NET%20MVC)

tried this but the images won't show, the images are inside my project

```
public void GetBeatles()
    {
        WebImage beatles = new    WebImage("../../Content/themes/base/images/classicrock/beatles.jpg");
        beatles.Write();
    }
```

Comment: Try with `new    WebImage("~/Content/themes/base/images/classicrock/beatles.jpg");`

Comment: Your Address does not match the same style. (It is likely your image url is wrong.)

Comment: my image is located in C:\Documents and Settings\Microsoft\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Town\Town\Content\themes\base\images\classicrock/beatles.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chari,

how about trying (in the controller):

```
WebImage beatles = new WebImage(HostingEnvironment
         .MapPath(@"~/Content/themes/base/images/classicrock/beatles.jpg"));

beatles.Write();
```

and in the view:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetBeatles")" />
```

the `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` part will resolve your path to the physical disk path based on its relationship to the content folder.